# What is the word for a benefit of a condition?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I feel that this is a difficult question for me to explain, so please feel free to reword my query.

In context, the protagonist is explaining to the reader that he does know whether he should feel honoured that his friends would have prefered to watch him - ahem - copulate due to his popularity, or rather disgusted and uncomfortable. I've chosen to phrase it like this:

> "It's a massive deal. And yes, we did [expect you to wait for us to watch]." Aline says, releasing me. I can't tell whether her response is _______ to my popularity, or, rather, something they should get checked out.

Someone suggested to me "**as a result of**", but this seems too ambiguous and I feel that it relies too heavily on context not given to indicate that the protagonist believes this is a *benefit* of his popularity. The word ***perquisite*** sprang to mind, but, given the colloquial tone of the narrator, it seemed inappropriate.

Many thanks.

Edit: The word **owing** does seem to work, but I'd prefer to rearrange the sentence in order to use it. I'm wondering if it loses its meaning:

> "It's a massive deal. And yes, we did [expect you to wait for us to watch]." AQline says, releasing me. I can't tell whether to **owe** her response to my popularity, or consider asking them to seek medical help."

Does this lose the initial meaning, or sound scrappy?

Comment: The rearrangement using *owe* would sound more natural using "I owe" rather than "to owe".  Did you not like *due*, as in "...her response is due to my popularity..."?

Comment: I knew it seemed a bit "off", thank you. Due works well, I'd just have prefered to use "owe". Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the word *owing* here, as in :

> I can't tell whether her response is owing to my popularily...

The word *due* would also work well.

Similar to your suggestion of "as a result of" would be "a function of", but here you would need to drop the marker *to*.

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t specified whether you want a noun or something else,
but you mention *a benefit* and *perquisite*,
so I assume that you’re amenable to a noun. 
I believe that ***tribute*** fits your sentence well:

> I can’t tell whether her response is ***a tribute*** to my popularity, …

Definitions:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tribute):
>
> - something given or contributed voluntarily as due or deserved
>
>   something (as material evidence or a formal attestation)
>     that indicates the worth, virtue, or effectiveness of the one in question
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tribute):
>
>   An act, statement, or gift
>     that is intended to show gratitude, respect, or admiration:
>   *‘the video is a tribute to the musicals of the 40s’*
>   - Something resulting from a particular quality or feature
>       and indicating its worth:
>       *‘his victory in the championship was a tribute to his persistence’*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tribute):
>
>   something that you do, say, or build
>     to show that you respect and admire someone or something
>   **tribute to**
>   :
>   *They showed the program as a tribute to the two men.*

Answer (score 0):

Is the word "alluding" a possible option. Meaning as per Merriam Webster dictionary is " to make indirect reference"

Comment: I like that word a lot, but I wouldn't consider it fitting in this writing. The word, by definition, implies subtly and, in context, it seems innapropriate considering the bluntness of the girl's response. Thank you, though.

Comment: "in envy" is one more option that may be considered. Thank you.

Comment: This again doesn't seem to be correct in context. It's more fake disappointment rather than actual jealously, and it pertains to his popularity, which he defines as a positive thing. "Envy" sounds too antagonal.